# M contains all ordinals

Tags: set-theory

Could you help me to prove the following: If $M$ is a transitive class such that $Def(M)\subseteq M$, then $On^M =On$ (only using this assumptions)?

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ thinks $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then indeed it is an ordinal, and so $\text{On}^M\subseteq\text{On}$. Since $M$ is transitive, it follows that whenever $\alpha$ is an ordinal of $M$, then every $\beta<\alpha$ is also an ordinal of $M$. Thus, either $\text{On}^M=\text{On}$ or $\text{On}^M$ is an ordinal itself. But in this latter case, it would be a definable subset of $M$, and hence an element of $M$ by your assumption that $\text{Def}(M)\subseteq M$. So $\text{On}^M=\text{On}$, as desired.